# Is there an upper bound on the determinant of the sum of positive definite (or semidefinite) matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, upper-lower-bounds

The Minkowski inequality,
$$ (\det (A+B) )^{1/n} \geq (\det(A))^{1/n} + (\det(B))^{1/n},$$
implies
$$ \det (A + B) \geq \det (A) + \det (B)$$
where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices.

If the matrices $A$ and $B$ are positive definite (or positive semidefinite), is there an upper bound on the determinant of the sum of matrices $A$ and $B$ (possibly in terms of $A$ and $\det(B)$ or in terms of $\det(A)$ and $B$)?

**While not possible in general (as pointed out in the comments), what if we have some constraint on the matrices or determinant (even if the constraint is on the entries of the matrices)? Is there any case/constraints we can add to compute an upper bound as a function of det(A) and B or det(B) and A?**

Comment: Certainly not in terms of $\det A$ and $\det B$: let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$, for example.

Comment: Good point. Any thought on if in terms of $\det (A)$ and $B$ or in terms of $A$ and $\det (B)$? I edited my question.

Comment: @user1551 The example you provide is for A positive semi definite. What if either A or B are positive definite?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If $A=diag(a,1/a)$ and $B=I$, then $\det(A)$ and $B$ are constant, but $\det(A+B)$ is unbounded above.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your comment. What if we have e.g., an upper bound for det(A) or det(B)? Just seems like given det(A) and B with some constraint, we should be able to say something about the upper bound of det(A+B).

Comment: No. Note that the $A$ in my previous comment has a constant determinant and $B$ is also constant.

Comment: @user1551 Is this right? This seems to be a possible solution to my question, which is your answer from another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/356847/372907

Comment: My previous comment doesn't contradict my answer. In my comment, $A$ is unbounded but in my answer, $A$ is bounded because $A,B\ge0$ and $A+B=I$.

Comment: @user1551 I didn't mean you answer contradicted your comment. Just seems that in you answer, $1+\det (A+C) \leq \det A + \det (I+C)$ is true in general because we can pick a $B$ such that $A+B = I$. I think. If true, your previous answer is indeed and answer to my question. Edit: I suppose if $B \geq 0$, maybe we can't pick $A+B = I$?

Comment: As I said, if $A+B=I$, then both $A$ and $B$ are bounded above, but in your question, they aren't.

Comment: @user1551 Perhaps, I don't understand the linked question/answer e.g., I don't understand why you could make the assumption that $A+B=I$ in the other question. As I said, based on that answer, why could we not pick a $B$ such that $A+B = I$, which gives $\det(A+C) \leq \det (A) + \det(I+C) - 1$ where $A$ and $C$ are positive definite matrices. Except in the other question, the $C$ would be our $B$...

Comment: We can assume that $A+B=I$ in the other question because the inequality is preserved if we left-multiply and right-multiply both sides by a $\det(A+B)^{-1/2}$. In other words, we define $A'=(A+B)^{-1/2}A(A+B)^{-1/2},\,B'=(A+B)^{-1/2}B(A+B)^{-1/2},\,C'=(A+B)^{-1/2}C(A+B)^{-1/2}$ and replace $A,B,C$ by $A',B'$ and $C'$ in the inequality. **We cannot do this here**, because the $A$ in your question is unbounded. If you plug in $A=diag(a,1/a)$ and $C=I$, you will see that the inequality $\det(A+C)\le\det(A)+\det(I+C)-1$ does not hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109303/discussion-between-ralff-and-user1551).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @user1551, no upper bound exists as a function of $A$ and $\det B$, or $B$ and $\det A$.
In other words, knowing $B$ and $\det A$ (or knowing $A$ and $\det B$) is not enough for $\det (A + B)$ to be bounded.
We need more information about $A$ or/and $B$.

Let $A$ and $B$ be both $n\times n$ positive definite Hermitian matrices.
We have the following upper bounds:
$$\det (A + B) \le \det A \det \left(I + \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}B\right) \tag{1}$$
and
$$\det (A + B)\le \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(B)}\right)^n\det A \det B \tag{2}$$
where $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$. Indeed, first,
we have
\begin{align}
\det (A + B) &= \det A \det (I + A^{-1}B)\\
& = \det A \det (I + B^{1/2} A^{-1}B^{1/2}) \\
&\le \det A \det \left(I + B^{1/2} \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}I B^{1/2}\right)\\
& = \det A \det \left(I + \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}B\right)
\end{align}
where we have used $A^{-1} \le \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}I$ (from $A\ge \lambda_{\min}(A) I$)
and $\det X \ge \det Y$ if $X, Y, X-Y$ are all positive semidefinite. Second, we have
$\det (A + B) = \det A \det (I + A^{-1}B) = \det A \det B \det (B^{-1} + A^{-1})$ and get (2) similarly.

Answer (score 4):

The examples in the comments show a bound on terms of only $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ is not possible. However, a bound based on the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ is possible. This may or may not answer your question (it doesn't answer the bolded question), but it may be interesting (or already known to you).

Let $\lambda^\uparrow(M)$ and $\lambda^\downarrow(M)$ denote vectors of the eigenvalues of $M$ listed in ascending and descending order respectively. We have the well-known [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) [relation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Majorization.html):

$$
\lambda^\downarrow(A)+\lambda^\uparrow(B)\prec \lambda^\downarrow(A+B).
$$

We know that the map $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_1\cdots x_n$ is an elementary symmetric polynomial and thus [Schur concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function). Thus

$$
\det (A+B)=\prod_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^\downarrow(A+B)\le \prod_{j=1}^n (\lambda_j^\downarrow (A)+\lambda_j^\uparrow(B)).
$$

The bound is tight for user1551's example from the comments $A = \operatorname{diag}(a,a^{-1})$ and $B = I$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn’t answer my question because the bound is a function of eigenvalues instead of A and det(B) (or B and det(A)). However, your answer is indeed insightful and interesting!