# $A,B$ are two real positive matrices then $\det (A+B) > \max(\det A , \det B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant

Let $A,B$ two square-real-positive matrices. Prove that $\det (A+B) > \max(\det A , \det B)$

So I found this solution:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41478/160028

Basically, if $A=I_n$ and $B$ is diagonal then the proof is immediate.

Now, I know that if $M$ is positive-symmetric then:

- $M$ is conjugate to $I_n$.
- $M$ is conjugate to $\text{Diag}(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ where $c_i > 0$.

but as far as I understand **it doesn't have to be the same $P$**. Anyhow, how do I utilize it in order to prove the inequality?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $\max(\det A+\det B)$?

Comment: corrected the typo, @HowDoIMath

Comment: The obligatory piece of pedantry: Not true for $0 \times 0$-matrices. :) This is actually a well-known fact, in one of its many forms. I remember posting a proof on MO or m.se, but search on stackexchange is... well, search on stackexchange. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices for even more general facts.

Comment: I know the duplicate question was actually linked from in the above question. That does not take away that OP is asking exactly the same thing here; I don't see why the answers at the linked question do not suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that a satisfactory $P$ exists as follows:

First, suppose we only have $P^TAP = I$. Then apply the spectral theorem to find an *orthogonal* $U$ such that $U^T(P^TBP)U = D$ is diagonal.  We then have
$$
(PU)^T(A + B)(PU) = \\
U^T(P^TAP)U + U^T(P^TBP)U = \\
U^T(I)U + D =\\
I + D
$$
So, the new matrix $PU$ does the job.